# Is it possible to get data from Confluence using Java without URL and username,password?

Tags: java, confluence

Want get result without username and password

## Below i put my code to get confluence details:

```
String userpass = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
String jsonPattern = null;

// get value from JSON URL
String sURL = "http://aa875db5.ngrok.io/confluence/rest/api/content?title="
                + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(map.get("Page").trim(), "UTF-8");
```

============================================================

Without `URL`,`Username` and `password` want get result

I don't have any error in this code but when put in Server.I want give server details that is the problem?

Comment: From a security standpoint, I would be *very* concerned if you could.

Comment: Ask the server admin for an API key.